# Meteor First load of route is fine. Then on returning to the route i get this: Error: Failed to execute 'insertBefore'

Tags: node.js, meteor, meteor-blaze

Exception from Deps recompute function: Error: Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': The node before which the new node is to be inserted is not a child of this node.
    at Error (native)
    at Function.DOMRange._insertNodeWithHooks

I think this is a problem with the rendering of my template.

I have no idea where to look to solve this problem? It just start happening when I clear down my database.

Here's my layout template:

```
    <div class="container">

        <navigation>
            {{> yield region='navigation'}}

            <leftmenu>
                    {{> yield region="leftmenu"}}
            </leftmenu>

            <rightmenu>
                    {{> yield region="rightmenu"}}
            </rightmenu>

        </navigation>


        <corezone>
            {{> yield}}
        </corezone>


    </div>

    <footer>
        {{> yield region='footer'}}
    </footer>
```

my iron router looks likes this:

```
Router.map(function () {

this.route('matching', {
path: '/', // match the root path
layoutTemplate: 'mylayout',
waitOn: function() {
      Meteor.subscribe('stuff');
      Meteor.subscribe('morestuff');
  return 
},
onBeforeAction: function () {
    if (! Meteor.user()) {
      if (Meteor.loggingIn()) {


        if (Matches.find({}).count()==0) {
          Router.go('profile');
        }
      }
      else{
        Router.go('loginscreen');
      }
    }
},
onAfterAction: function() {
      $("#menuleft").mmenu({
                offCanvas   : {
                    position    : 'left'
                },

                classes     : 'mm-light',
                dragOpen    : true,
                counters    : true,
                searchfield : true,
                header      : {
                    add         : true,
                    update      : true,
                    title       : 'Menu'
                }
            });
},
yieldTemplates: {
  'newNav': {to: 'navigation'},
  'menuright': {to: 'rightmenu'},
  'menuleft': {to: 'leftmenu'}

}
}),
```

Comment: Can you post some of your code?

Comment: just added my template

Comment: Need to post code of the page where the error pops up when you load it. For my case, i noticed its a problem with Template.name.onRendered for example in the js files